# Owl Carousel marquee PREV button not working good

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a owl carousel marquee like scroll.
Everything is fine. But the PREV button is not working good all the time.

You can see the example [here](https://codepen.io/subir/pen/eYYxLER). Please help

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var owl = $('.owl-carousel');
owl.owlCarousel({
    items: 8,
    loop: true,
    margin: 20,
    nav:true,
    autoplay: true,
    slideTransition: 'linear',
    autoplayTimeout: 0,
    autoplaySpeed: 3000,
    autoplayHoverPause: false

 });

});
```

Comment: Not sure what is not working. It seems to be working. What are you expecting it to do?

Comment: The "PREV" button is not working smooth like the "NEXT" button. Please check it carefully

Comment: @ScottPurtan clicking on the next button skips two elements but not when you click on the previous button.

Comment: @MuraliNepalli - you are right. That is the issue

Comment: It would have been better to describe what @MuraliNepalli had said in the comment in the original post. That saves everyone's time. The description like "is not working good" is too vague to understand the expected behavior.

Comment: @yaobin - What "Murali" said is exact issue- "clicking on the next button skips two elements but not when you click on the previous button.". Please look at the link. I really need your help. clicking on the prev button is not going backward if i click again and again.

Comment: @FlyingWeaver Yes, I know that's the issue. Sorry, I don't have the knowledge to help with this technical question. I'm trying to say if you describe the expected behavior in the original post rather than letting someone else clarify that for you, it would be easier and quicker for those who know how to solve the issue to understand the question and help you.

Comment: @FlyingWeaver so what is the issue? You want it to skip 2 going prev instead of 1. Or is it the skipping 2 is what you need fixed?

Comment: You definitely have a weird issue going on. I implemented slideby = 2 and it worked for a few times and then went back to only 1 and then the forward started doing 4 at a time. I think there might be something going on with the version of carousel you are using..

Comment: I have played with this a bit. I believe that your issue is based on the amount of items you have and how many you are showing on the page. You have 8 and are showing 8. Then scrolling. it seems that it is always trying to reach the end of the images. It also seems to matter where the image is in the scroll as to how many it goes forward or back. I would try adding more images and only showing 8. See it that helps. You can look at this post as well to give you some more ideas. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21045951/slide-2-items-in-owl-carousel

Comment: @ScottPurtan - I tried with all the options you said. But no luck. I also checked the link you gave. Not working Boss !!